# Does the PDE $u_{tt} = a u_{xx} + b u_{xxxx}$ have a name?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, wave-equation

I stumbled upon an interesting PDE in my work, but failed to find its name or type (if it has one).

$$u = u(x,t)$$

$$u_{tt} = a u_{xx} + b u_{xxxx}$$

Here the subscripts denote partial derivatives, while $a$ and $b$ are some real constants. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do not understand the question. How does one define the terms in a Riccati or a KdV equation? The function u measures displacement of a traveling soliton.

Comment: The terms seem perfectly well-defined to me since you stated that subscripts denote partial derivatives.

Comment: This looks like the beam equation from Elasticity theory. See: http://www.math.umbc.edu/~jbell/pde_notes/20_Beam%20Equation.pdf

Comment: Indeed, it is the free vibration of a uniform beam undergoing transverse vibration under axial tensile force. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a>0$ and $b<0$, then this equation is also known as the *stiff string* wave equation, which models the transverse motion of a non-ideal string by accounting for bending stiffness (see e.g. [link1](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/pasp/Dispersive_1D_Wave_Equation.html), [link2](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Stiff_String.html), [link3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05516.pdf)). It belongs to the class of linear dispersive wave equations.